# Know any micropipettor that is acid resistant?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

We pipet concentrated nitric and hydrochloric acids. our current pipettor is rainin lite but its piston is metal and thus corrode easily.  We discussed this with our inhouse technician and he suggested a pipettor with a plastic piston.  So do you guys know any?

We try to avoid using filtered tips as we need to leach the tips prior to use.

Thanks